# how to access the id of a ManyToManyField object?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, manytomanyfield

my models:

```
class Aula(models.Model):
    
    nome_aula = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    descricao_aula = models.TextField()
    
    ...
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome_aula

class Modulos(models.Model):

    numero_modulo = models.CharField(default="Módulo 1",max_length=400)

    aulas = models.ManyToManyField(Aula)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.numero_modulo
```

my views:

```
def aulasdomodulo(request, id):

    mod = get_object_or_404(Modulos, pk=id)

    aulas = mod.aulas.all()


    return render(request, 'wtic/aulasdomodulo.html', {'aulas':aulas, 'mod':mod})

def conteudodaaula(request, id):

    mod2 = get_object_or_404(Modulos, pk=id)

    aula = mod2.aulas.all()

    ...

    return render(request,'wtic/conteudo_aula.html', {'aula':aula})
```

my html where it shows the objects assigned that module accesses them

```
{% for aula in aulas %}

{{aula.nome_aula}}
<a href="/aula/{{aula.id}}">Acessar</a>

{% endfor %}
```

[image]

but when I try to access classes I get it

[image]

how can i access these objects one per page?

Comment: Can you show your URLs configuration?

Comment: You use the id of `Aula` instance to make a url that expects ids of `Modulos` which is why you get the error.